# Resisze grid to fit tkinter window

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tk-toolkit

Hey so im trying to get to grips with tkinter so i can use it fully in my programs, however im struggling with the geometry manager, grid.

I want my program to resize the grid, based upon the size of the widnow, is there any way to do this? This is my code so far:

```
import tkinter
import time
import random
import sqlite3
window=tkinter.Tk()
window.title("Phone Book")
window.wm_iconbitmap('favicon (2).ico')
window.geometry("300x400")

entlbl1=tkinter.Label(window, text ="Add A Contact", font=("Helvetica", 23))
entlbl2=tkinter.Label(window, text ="Name:", font=("Helvetica", 16))
entlbl3=tkinter.Label(window, text ="Phone:", font=("Helvetica", 16))
entlbl4=tkinter.Label(window, text ="E-Mail:", font=("Helvetica", 16))
entbox1=tkinter.Entry(window)
entbox2=tkinter.Entry(window)
entbox3=tkinter.Entry(window)
entbtn1=tkinter.Button(window, text = "Add")
entbtn2=tkinter.Button(window, text = "Menu")
blanklbl=tkinter.Label(window)

entlbl1.grid(row=0,columnspan=4)
entlbl2.grid(row=1,sticky="w")
entlbl3.grid(row=2,sticky="w")
entlbl4.grid(row=3,sticky="w")
entbox1.grid(row=1, column=1)
entbox2.grid(row=2, column=1)
entbox3.grid(row=3, column=1)
entbtn1.grid(row=5,columnspan=2,sticky="WE")
entbtn2.grid(row=6,columnspan=2, sticky="WE")
blanklbl.grid(row=4)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When there is extra space in a window managed by grid, it allocates that extra space to rows and columns that have a non-zero "weight". To get your rows and columns to expand, give them a non-zero weight.

```
for row in range(7):
    window.grid_rowconfigure(row, weight=1)
for col in range(3):
    window.grid_columnconfigure(col, weight=1)
```

Of course, adjust that to whatever number of rows and columns you're actually using. You can give different weights to cause some rows or columns to grow more than others. For example, a column with a weight of 3 will grow 3 times faster than a column with a weight of 1.